# Несколько значений в условии php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Есть код

```
$banned = "<center><h1>Вы заблокированы в данном приложении</h1></center>";
        if($_GET['viewer_id'] == 1 && 2){
        echo $banned;
        return;
    }
```

Проблема в том что пользователь с ID 2 всё рано может войти на страницу.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: опиши проблему более подробно.. что ты хочешь сделать..и больше кода

Comment: Что бы пользователи с ID который есть в условии не могли просматривать страницу.

Comment: `$_GET['viewer_id'] == 1 && 2)`  замените на `$_GET['viewer_id'] == 1 && $_GET['viewer_id'] == 2)`

Comment: Можно сделать это как нибудь короче?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie say Pie .я думаю что  там нужно ||

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, точно, спутал, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_GET['viewer_id'] == 1 || $_GET['viewer_id'] == 2) {
    return $banned;
}
```

Если, это длинная запись, то можно сделать массив с идентификаторами и проверять так:

```
$uids = [1, 2];

if (in_array($_GET['viewer_id'], $uids)) {
    return $banned;
}
```